# multi insert use async await

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public async Task BulkInsert(List<WagerInfo> wagers)
{
    var tasks = wagers.Select(async x => await insert(x));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
private Task insert(WagerInfo wager)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        db.Wagers.Add(wager);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    sw.Stop();

    log("save one record spent : " + sw.Elapsed);
}
```

It is a simple code for insert records.

but the log shows saved one record spent more then one second sometimes.

> save one record spent : 00:00:00.0180819
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:00.0239751
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:00.0089301
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:00.0116161
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:00.0736537
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:00.0711155
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:03.1613426
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:03.1703909
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:03.1727551
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:07.8156325
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:07.8137410
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:07.8179925
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:00.0079545
>
> save one record spent : 00:00:00.0074952

But my DBA said he doesn't catch any alert of executed time over then 4 seconds.

why there are some records insert over then 1 second ?

if I change insert method to ado.net will be better ?

Comment: There issue with connection pool setting ..  due to pool of connection it is waiting in getting contention and you log is a adding that time to sql execution time ... log timing once u got connection ....

Comment: thank your tip! I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Saving changes is  optimized for multiple inserts in the same transaction.

Split the list in chunks of 500 or 1000 inserts.

Then call your `Task insert` with a `List <WagerInfo>` to be added before the `SaveChangesAsync`

Answer (score 0):

You're right. When you need to insert a large records into database, you should use ADO.Net.

You can visit this link to refer, my friend :)

https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/